# mysql update query not working with high numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL UPDATE query to decrease some value in my table named `users`. Below is the `CREATE TABLE` script for the `users` table

```
CREATE TABLE users 
( 
    user_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    username varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    email varchar(60) NOT NULL, 
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    money float NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I use the following query:

```
UPDATE users SET money = money - 1000 WHERE user_id = 1;
```

It's working fine.

but when 'money' value is a high number (for example 33550400000) it just does nothing. When I manually execute the query in phpMyAdmin it prints `0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0003 seconds.)`

How can I make it work with high numbers?

Comment: may be datatype doesnot handle this big value

Comment: Float is a very bad choice for money.

Comment: @jarlh so what should I use instead of float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "decimal" datatype in sql for money column. It works fine.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Now I can't set high numbers at all.
When I try to set 'money' value to 33550400000 , it throws this error: 
  #1264 - Out of range value for column 'money' at row 1

Comment: Have you changed column datatype to decimal?

Comment: Use decimal(10,0) or decimal(10,2).  In Length field while changing datatype, fill 10,0 and save

Comment: I did it. In the structure page, I see "decimal(10,0)" for 'money'. but it still throws this error.

Comment: the value 10,2 or 10,0 is for example  your value is of 11 digits so set either 11,2 or any other value according to your data. 11 is for number of digits and 2 is for decimal places